# CDF of non-standard normal random variable in OpenBUGS

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, bugs

I need to use the cumulative density function (CDF) a normal random variable with mean 0 and standard deviation which is not 1, but I do not know which function to use.

I know the CDF of the standard normal random variable is phi(), but now I need to use the CDF of a non-standard normal random variable with mean 0 and standard deviation unequal to 1.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and if $\Phi$ denotes the *cdf* of a standard normal distribution, then the *cdf* of $X$ is $$q \mapsto \Phi\left(\frac{q - \mu}{\sigma}\right).$$ So use `phi(q/sigma)` in OpenBUGS.